# Append a tensor vector to tensor matrix

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor matrix that i simply want to append a tensor vector as another column to it.

For example:

```
    X = torch.randint(100, (100,5))
    x1 = torch.from_numpy(np.array(range(0, 100)))
```

I've tried `torch.cat([x1, X)` with various numbers for both `axis` and `dim` but it always says that the dimensions don't match.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`torch.hstack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.hstack.html#torch-hstack) to combine and [`unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html) for reshape `x1`

```py
torch.hstack([X, x1.unsqueeze(1)])
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for and was trying to use but wouldn't work.  Based on you saying it should be a thing i investigated further.  The container we use has pytorch 1.6._ whereas this function was added in 1.7  So frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Shape of X is [100, 5], while the shape of X1 is 100. For concatenation torch requires similar shape on all the axis apart from the one in which we are trying to concatenate.

so, you will first need to

```
X1 = X1[:, None] # change the shape from 100 to [100, 1]
Xc = torch.cat([X, X1], axis=-1) /# tells the torch that we need to concatenate over the last dimension
```

Xc.shape should be [100, 6]

Comment: I believe a comment starts with `#` and not `//` in Python. Also consider changing the variable `O` to some other name.

Comment: what is the -1 axis? Wouldnt the 2nd axis of a, now, 2d shape be axis=1?

Comment: In python, -1 implies the last element which would be 1 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the two answers into a pytorch 1.6 compatible version:

`torch.cat((X, x1.unsqueeze(1)), dim = 1)`